# What happens if a positively charged object $+5q$ touches a negative charged object $-1q$?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

What happens if a positively charged object +5q touches a negative charged object -1q?
Does the charge go from the negative object to the positive and they are left the first object with the charge +4q and the second object neutral?
Or do both the object get charged in the same way,both with the charge +2q?

Comment: What kind of objects? Insulator or conductors? Anyway, there is no general answer. It depends on the specific objects.

Comment: @nasu they are identical metal spheres

Comment: LIke charges repel; unlike charges attract.

Comment: This seems like a homework problem.  Not typically what the forum entertains.

Comment: 10q. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

When two charged conductive objects touch, the total net charge gets distributed between them according to their capacitance: the object with greater capacitance will get proportionally greater charge.

If the objects are identical, like two spheres, each will get one half of the net charge.

Comment: So both of the spheres will be charged +2q,right?

Comment: @LedjaNushi You got it.